# Issue in Ordering of JavaScript libraries

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have basically two set of imports of libraries for two different purposes, one is for a pallet type thing which contains lots of buttons, code for that is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/accordion_glam.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/accordion.js"></script>
```

Other one is highcharts imports

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='highcharts.js'></script>
```

Now the problem is, if i place the first block before the second one, it dont work, so you can say that in order, the one at the second number wors for example, if i write them like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='highcharts.js'></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/accordion_glam.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/accordion.js"></script>
```

Then highcharts won't work but pallet will work and vice verca, i tried many different combinations of ordering but the problem persists.

Comment: Have you looked into Conflict issues and console errors?

Comment: No, i dont know how to do that, im using Dreamweaver

Answer (score 0):

If your JavaScript code is doing something like this:

```
// Define some functions...
var myFunction = function() {
   // ...
};


// Do some initialization
myFunction();
```

...  you should really separate this code into:

```
 (function(){
 window.mypackage = window.mypackage || {};

 // Define some functions
 window.mypackage.myFunction = function() {
    // ...
 };

 // Register initializers
 window.mypackage.initializers = window.mypackage.intializers || [];
 window.mypackage.initializers.push(window.mypackage.myFunction);
 })();
```

and a separate JavaScript file for actually executing the initialization:

```
for (var i = 0; i < mypackage.initializers.length; ++i) {
  mypackage.initializers[i]();
}
```

That way you can load all the function definitions, first, and only run the initialization logic after everything is available. Furthermore, I would highly recommend moving your JavaScript out of the head section, since that delays the loading/rendering of the page.

The website html5rocks has [an excellent article on loading scripts](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/) that I highly recommend reading. The basic approach is to list the scripts in the head section as "subresource"s so that the browser can immediately begin fetching them but to defer execution to the bottom of the body by including the scripts at the bottom of the body section. Combine that with separating the definitions of functions with initialization that relies on them, and you should be golden.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts allows to use `prototype` instead of jquery, so you dont need to use this framework.

See the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/zUK5k/